# How to calculate the number of times the car's velocity is zero

Tags: anylogic

I have a model built on the Road Transport Library and I have cars inside a city. These cars form a queue due to an intersection. And I would like to know the number of times the cars stop while they are on that queue

I have tried to create a parameter inside my car agent that would increment everytime that specific car speed would reach 0

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: what you are doing is fine... increment variable when speed=0...

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with this library, but it seems that there are several solutions to your problem.

1 Create an event with a very high frequency inside the car that will calc its current speed. Next, it's simple technique to find out how often speed is zero. This method is good because it is simple. however, you may miss some car deliveries if you event will not restart too often

2 a better and more elegant way is to use a state chart diagram. and control the movement of you car through it. i.e. the car stops only when it is in the stop state. it is important that the state itself should control the speed of the car. I.e., some event should arrive in the diagram that puts the car in a stop state. the number of times that car will be in this state is you answer